# The Birth of Vali and Sugriva

Tags: ramayana, vali, sugriva

Wikipedia mentions

> Aruna, once became a woman named Aruni and entered an assembly of celestial nymphs, where no man except the king of Heaven - Indra was allowed. Indra fell in love with Aruni and fathered a son named Vali from her. The next day, at Surya's request, Aruna again assumed female form, and Surya fathered a son, Sugriva. Both children were given to Ahalya for rearing, but her husband sage Gautama cursed them, causing them to turn into monkeys, as he did not like them

Why did Aruna, the Charioteer of Surya assume the form of a women and what scriptures mention this story?

Comment: As far as i know there is **no** mention of this story in Valmiki Ramayana.

Comment: What does Ramayana claim regarding the birth of Vali and Sugriva?

Comment: @Shashaank Ramayana says : Vali and Sugriva were born of Riksharajas. Indra and Surya had to take on the form of women and produce Vali and Sugriva respectively. Riksharajas is then given the kingdom of Kishkindha and then Vali inherits it.

Comment: Thank you @Adiyarkku

Comment: for what Valmiki Ramayana says, see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37938/clarity-regarding-valis-father-and-his-golden-pendant/37939?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C30.7916#37939